# HTML parsing of website inspect element by VBA

Tags: html, vba

I need to extract some image src data of the website. i wrote some code, but it is not working .

```
Sub getSrcAttributeImgTag()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim ElementCol As Object, Link As Object
    Dim ecol As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = False

    ie.navigate "http://test.site/showadv.php?rstr=0.8809384451371399"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop

    Set html = ie.document
    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("img")

    For Each Link In ElementCol
        ecol = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Column
        Cells(1, ecol).Value = Link.src
        Cells(1, ecol).Columns.AutoFit
    Next

    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

HTML As follows

```
  <form name="mainf" onsubmit="javascript:dosub();return false;">
  <div align="center">
  <table>
  <tbody><tr>
  <td><div id="cimg1"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/4.png"> 
  </div></td>
  <td><div id="cimg2"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/3.png"> 
  </div></td>
  <td><div id="cimg3"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/3.png"> 
   </div></td>
  <td><div id="cimg4"><img width="35" height="55" src="images/capchs/5.png"> 
   </div></td>
  <td><div id="cimg5">&nbsp;</div></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
</div><br>
<div align="center">
 <input type="text" name="capcha" value="" 
style="width:200px;height:30px;font-size:15px;">
</div><br><br>
<div align="center">
<input type="button" value="CONTINUE" style="width:200px;height:30px;font- 
size:15px;" onclick="javascript:dosub()">
</div><br><br>
<div align="center">
<br>
 </div><br><br>
 </form>
```

But my VBA code not working for inspect element HTML.

the result should be in excel A ="images/capchs/5.png" etc

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's really surprising that most of the people while trying to automate stuff from web using vba, they tend to provide either `inaccessible url` or any `placeholder for url`. I don't understand why it is that. Vba coding and numerology are not identical things.

Comment: @Topto - This is internal web server, not accessible from outside.

Comment: Well at the very least provide a decent bit of HTML to narrow things down from pure divination. And what does not working mean? What **should** happen, and what **is** happening? Any error codes?

Comment: could you parse the html above if you are simply after that png?

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply parse the response text?

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = Range("A1").Text '<==this would actually be your response HTML
    Dim arr() As String, i As Long
    arr = Split(a, "src=")

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Debug.Print Replace(Split(arr(i), ">")(0), Chr(34), vbNullString)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which might look something like:

```
Public Sub getSrcAttributeImgTag()
    Const ecol As Long = 1
    Dim responseString As String, i As Long, arr()

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", "http://test.site/showadv.php?rstr=0.8809384451371399", False
        .send
         responseString = .responseText
    End With

    arr = Split(responseString, "src=")

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ecol) = Replace(Split(arr(i), ">")(0), Chr(34), vbNullString)
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, ecol).Columns.AutoFit
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am assuming that waits are not a big problem but if they are then you could loop until page loaded, which you seem to know how to do already. Furthermore, you can also introduce waits with `Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(h,m,s)`

Hard to tell with only the above but you might get something working with

something like `document.querySelectorAll("div img")`

Comment: while doing this code, i am getting different html as we are getting through view source page of browser. what i put html is getting through inspect element. how will do for inspect element?

Comment: I can't debug without an URL  (and I note that this is an internal so can't be share) so offered the above as possibilities. If the html changes each time will it be impossible to parse the html? Also, can you look into using the css selector I mentioned? You may find something like that you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to inspect the TD elements pretty easily.  Here is a generic solution.  Just customize it for your specific, not accessible, scenario.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Web_Table_Option_One()
    Dim xml    As Object
    Dim html   As Object
    Dim objTable As Object
    Dim result As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lngTable As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim ActRw As Long
    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", "http://www.ewrinc.com/cotton/contentPublic/reports/stateReceipts.aspx", False
        .send
    End With
    result = xml.responseText
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = result
    Set objTable = html.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    For lngTable = 0 To objTable.Length - 1
        For lngRow = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length - 1
            For lngCol = 0 To objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells.Length - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(ActRw + lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = objTable(lngTable).Rows(lngRow).Cells(lngCol).innerText
            Next lngCol
        Next lngRow
        ActRw = ActRw + objTable(lngTable).Rows.Length + 1
    Next lngTable
End Sub
```